# Validation for integer number

Tags: javascript

I have created one form.In that form,it put one textbox.That text box should take only integer not character or float.So I applied validation like this.Does it right?

```
var a = document.getElementById('textbox1').value;
var b = /^\d+$/;

If (a.search(b) == -1)
{
alert(Must be Interger);
return false;
}
```

Comment: you should use b.test(a). and alert should contain string in quotes ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will work, unless it's allowed to take a negative integer, in which case you need to add `-?` (optional negative sign) before the `\d`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script for Integer validation .

```
   var value = Number(intfield.value);
if (Math.floor(value) == value) {
  // value is integer, do something based on that
} else {
  // value is not an Integer, show validation alerts
}
```

Comment: `1asdfasdf` is not a valid number.

Comment: More like changed completely. Now `0x1` and `10e-1` are valid.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var textboxValue = document.getElementById('textbox1').value;

if (!textboxValue.test(/^\d+$/)){
    alert('Must be Interger');
    return false;
}
```

Its a good practice to put easy names to vars or you will be lost months later whan you review your code :D

Answer (score -1):

Hi I think below answer will be the better so that you can implement multiple TextBoxes

```
 <script> 
     function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 45 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Thanks
Bhanu Prakash

Comment: Why 'return false; return true;' continuously ?